# How to read the contents of a text file on a user's computer within asp.net web app?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis-7, vb.net-2010

using vb.net, .net 4.0..

I'm trying to read the contents of a text file on a user's computer from my IIS deployed web app.
Now, in local debug mode, I have no issue reading the contents of my computer, it's just that when I publish it, I can no longer obtain a value.

here's what I have,

Here's the function :

```
Public Function GetFileContents(ByVal FullPath As String, _
   Optional ByRef ErrInfo As String = "") As String

    Dim strContents As String
    Dim objReader As StreamReader
    Try

        objReader = New StreamReader(FullPath)
        strContents = objReader.ReadToEnd()
        objReader.Close()
        Return strContents
    Catch Ex As Exception
        ErrInfo = Ex.Message
    End Try
End Function
```

Calling the function and returning the contents:

```
sContents = GetFileContents("C:\Location.txt", String.Empty)
```

In my Site.Master pageload, assigning the variable with data:

```
UserInfo.Text = Global_asax.sContents
```

Again, locally, all fine and dandy...running over the web server. No luck.

I am trying to obtain information pertaining to this user w/o having them to provide the information. Reading from a text file seemed like a good idea.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Your VB.NET code runs *on the server*. It should be no surprise that it's not able to directly access client's files.

Answer (score 1):

You can not access your local computer's files directly, when using ASP.NET on a remote server.  The server can only access it's local file structure, so it works for you only in the site / file are on the same machine.  You can extend this a bit further to include UNC shares, anywhere on your network, but you can not access files from your computer, when your web site is hosted elsewhere.

What you need to do is use the browser to upload the local file to the remote server, after which the routine you have will work as expected.

Here's some sample code to get you started:  [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479405.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the link, it looks good. I'm going to investigate using that control  and automate the process in order to make it seamless to the user. I just wish to obtain the information in a particular/known file and parse that information. Thanks again. I'll get back to this thread shortly.